# How to aggregate an array of struct in spark with group by

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, distribution

I'm using Spark 2.1. I have a dataframe with this schema:

```
scala> df.printSchema

|-- id: integer (nullable = true)
|-- sum: integer (nullable = true)
|-- distribution: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- lower: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- upper: integer (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to aggregate:

- Group by "id" column
- Sum of "sum" and "count" within "distribution" (grouping by "lower" and "upper")

Here I can not explode the dataframe, since I will have duplicated row and can not do the sum of "sum" column. One possibility is to do the sum and aggregation of distribution separately, then joining by "id", but an user-defined function will be way simpler.

As input, I have:

```
scala> df.show(false)

+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sum|distribution                                                |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |1  |[[0,1,2]]                                                   |
|1  |1  |[[1,2,5]]                                                   |
|1  |7  |[[0,1,1], [1,2,6]]                                          |
|1  |7  |[[0,1,5], [1,2,1], [2,3,1]]                                 |
|2  |1  |[[0,1,1]]                                                   |
|2  |2  |[[0,1,1], [1,2,1]]                                          |
|2  |1  |[[0,1,1]]                                                   |
|2  |1  |[[2,3,1]]                                                   |
|2  |1  |[[0,1,1]]                                                   |
|2  |4  |[[0,1,1], [1,2,1], [2,3,1], [3,4,1]]                        |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sum|distribution                                                |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |16 |[[0,1,8], [1,2,12], [2,3,1]]                                |
|2  |10 |[[0,1,5], [1,2,2], [2,3,3], [3,4,1]]                        |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, IntegerType, StructField, StructType}


# schema to be used in the UDF to have this format in output this format as output of your 
val schema: ArrayType = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
      StructField("lower", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("upper", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("count", IntegerType, false)
    )))

val customAggregation = udf((xs: Seq[Seq[Row]]) =>
  xs.flatten.map(row => (
    row.getAs[Int]("lower"),
    row.getAs[Int]("upper"),
    row.getAs[Int]("count")
  ))
    .groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2))
    .mapValues(_.map(_._3).sum).toSeq
    .map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2)), schema
)


val df: DataFrame = df_input
.groupBy("id")
.agg(sum("sum"),collect_list("distribution"))
.toDF("id", "sum" ,"distribution")
.withColumn("distribution_agg", flatten(col("distribution")))
```

result will be

```
scala> dfOutput.select("id","sum","distribution_agg").show
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sum|distribution                                                |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |16 |[[0,1,8], [1,2,12], [2,3,1]]                                |
|2  |10 |[[0,1,5], [1,2,2], [2,3,3], [3,4,1]]                        |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
```